# Does Flutter have ViewBinding?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there view binding in Flutter?

I have checked the official documentation about the field changes but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Use StreamBuilder to wrap your widget which will be changed later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.